# Class instance used by other classes factory methods. How to remove duplicated code?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I've a base class named `API` which is used by three objects(Server, VPS, SharedHosting).

Code:

```
class API:

  def get(endpoint, params):

  def post(endpoint, params):

  def parse_response(response):
```

Server class:

```
class Server:

    def __init__(self, name, ip):
        self.name = name
        self.ip = ip


    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        api = API()
        server = api.post("/server")
        return Server(server['name'], server['ip'])

    @classmethod
    def find(cls, vm_id):
        api = Api()
        server = api.get("/server/:id")
        return Server(server['name'], server['ip'])
```

VPS and SharedHosting are very similar to Server class. As you can see every time I call factory methods I need to create an instance of API class. How would you do that?Inheritance is an option in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The `API` object is a dependency of the Server, VPS and SharedHosting classes. Pass the API in as a constructor argument to all of them.